Laravel API with postman general error at 1364 Field

Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value
(Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into posts (post, updated_at,
created_at) values (Bruhhhh, 2024-05-25 12:35:55, 2024-05-25
12:35:55)) in file
C:\Users\Bence\Downloads\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php
on line 813

Why am I getting this error in postman for this route?
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts/
POST

x-www-form-urlencoded
Key: post
Value: Bruhhhh

In this example project I'm using a laravel database person and postman to to test the CRUD methods.
This simple project is handling the person's comments, and posts in the database, you can add new posts and comments database with postman, you could delete, update or read with postman if its would work.
Set up steps by steps
composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app
php artisan i api
php artisan make:model model_name -mfsc
Migration table
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table-\>id();
$table-\>foreignId('user_id')-\>constrained('users');
$table-\>string("post");
$table-\>timestamps();
});

//user model
public function posts(): HasMany
{
return $this-\>hasMany(Post::class);
}

public function comments(): HasMany
{
return $this-\>hasMany(Comment::class);
}

//post model
public function user(): BelongsTo
{
return $this-\>belongsTo(User::class);
}

Fillable example

protected $fillable = \[
'user_id',
'post'
\];

Factory example
User::factory(5)
\-\>has(Post::factory(3))
\-\>has(Comment::factory(3))
\-\>create();

Post controller:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::all();

        return response()->json($posts);
    }

    /**
     * Create a resource in storage.
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $post = Post::create($request->all());

        return response()->json(['success' => $post->id.' has been created.']);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);

        return response()->json($post);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);

        $post->update($request->all());

        return response()->json($post->id . ' has been updated.');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        Post::destroy($id);

        return response()->json($id . ' has been deleted.');
    }
}

API.php
Route::resource('/posts', PostController::class);


Are you sure your problem is related to Postman or JSON? Would this work different when using any other way to send the data?

Adjust your store method to something like this
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $post = Post::create([
        'user_id'=>auth()->id()
        'post'=>$request->post,
    ]);

    return response()->json(['success' => $post->id.' has been created.']);
}

I assume that the user is authenticated when creating a post, if its not the case then you will have to make the user_id field nullable in the migration
$request->all() is considered very insecure and the issue is you have user_id field not nullable in migration while you are not passing it to the query that's why it's showing that error
learn more about Laravel Eloquent here
